# .net 5 Web API - Auth using Identity and Microsoft AD Both

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I am have a web api in which I am looking for auth using a JWT token and Microsoft AD both.

The login page would have

1. Login button - This will validate users created using Identity.
2. Microsoft login button - this will validate users with microsoft ad login. Post the first login, I will be saving the user details in the identity tables.

I am was able to get the identity working using the UserManager and SignInManager where I am generating a JWT token if the all the checks are passed.

Now I have to add Microsoft Login to this web API middleware which I am not sure of. Any suggestions or links would be appreciated.

This will be in .net core Web Api. The UI will be angular or HTML based, so I am not sure how microsoft login will go in a web api Controller and what will be the params

FYI - I am looking to do this without IdentityServer if that is possible

Answer (score 0):

**1.** **Install Microsoft.Identity.Web library in your web api project**

- Right click on the project and manage nuget packages and search for
  Microsoft.Identity.Web    Library .
- Add >>
  Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration)  in
  startup.cs  class

```js
    
     

 using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //other code
            //

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd");
            //
           //other code
        }
```

**2. In app settings.json, copy paste application(client id)   and tenant
id  from azure ad in the client id**
[image]

---

**appsettings.json**

```js
{
  "Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Warning",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
 }
  },
 "AllowedHosts": "*",
"AzureAd": {
   "Instance": https://login.microsoftonline.com/,
   "ClientId": "93134054-xxxx",
   "TenantId": "aacd4f65-xxxx",
   "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
},
}
```

[image]

**3. In configure() method of  startup.cs class, Add  middleware (on top
of app.UseAuthorization();)**

```js
app.UseAuthentication(); 
app.Use(async(context,next)=>
{
If(!context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated??false)
{
Context.Response.StatusCode=401;
Await context.Response.WriteAsync(“User is Not Authenticated ”);
}
Else await next();
});
```

**4. Construct the URI** like below.
example:

```js
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT ID>/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=<AD APP CLIENT ID>
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2F // Redirect URL
&resource=<AD APP CLIENT ID>
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

This uri can be configured by using endpoints section in azure ad
Give values for your AD Tenant and the AD Application details in the
URL above.

(Endpoint can be taken from azure ad portal endpoint 2 as image below and can  be pasted in the first  line of above url.)

[image]

- Add client ID copied in place of client id and resource id of uri .
- Copy redirect uri from authentication section in azure ad  and
  paste in the &redirect_uri parameter

**5. Then Go to the appregistrations>api >authentication >select the
access tokens as the implicit grant flow**

[image]

**6. Controllers can use  the [Authorize] attribute.**

```js
namespace webapi.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class YourApiController : ControllerBase
...
...
//
.
.
```

Note: Modify the real API endpoint while calling it.

Refer [this](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/jwt_authentication_asp_net_web_api/) for more information.
Also see [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/setup-asp-net-core-web-apis-to-use-azure-ad-authentication/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. These settings on Azure and stuff was already done.
Then, I had added AddOpenIdConnect() and AddCookie() after AddJwtBearer(). 
In AddOpenIdConnect() I am adding the azureAd values. And finally created a GET api for MS Login which returns
return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                      OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

The another API of type POST uses Identity and _userManager and SignInManager. 

Will this work ? Is that a bad design?